# How can I make my other calendars visible from my Outlook calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

Is there a way that people who look at my Outlook calendar can see free-busy information from my other calendars, like iCloud, Google, etc.?

On my Mac desktop, I can link all many different calendars to the Calendar app and see all of that stuff at a glance. When I want, I can add a new calendar. And that's kind of what I'd like to do with Outlook, but -from- Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which Outlook Version you are using but the following steps should work:

- Go to your Google Calender Page --> Settings --> Calender --> On the right of the calender you want in Outlook, you can set the public options
- Configure your public options
- Copy the URL provided
- Open the Outlook Calender
- On the left side --> My Calenders
- Right Click --> Add Calender --> From the Web --> Paste the given URL
- The Calender should now show up in your Outlook

The names of the options may not be 100% accurate as I don't have an English version at hand, but you should find them along the provided path.

Comment: Makes sense, but I can't find the way to do this on my Mac version of Outlook.

Comment: I'm afraid adding the calendars doesn't add free/busy information, or at least for me it doesn't and I haven't found a way to do that.