# How do I automatically add events from a subscribed calendar to Outlook so I show as 'busy' during them?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

In Outlook (connecting from my Mac to an Office365 subscription) I have "my calendar" which carries all my meetings etc, and then I have several subscribed calendars - one from our HR system including my leave and one that just lists public holidays.

Unfortunately this only appears to work from the Calendar view of Outlook - it allows me to see all the calendars side by side or overlaid - but when I export my calendar to another application (eg Teams) or if someone tries to create an appointment with me, it blocks out the content of my calendar but not my leave calendar or the public holiday one.

Is there a way to either automatically add events from a subscribed calendar to my main calendar (in a way that means if the subscribed calendar is updated the events are updated too) *or* to configure my publicly available calendar as an aggregate of my subscribed calendars rather than only my core one?

I guess I could copy events over manually but it feels a little ridiculous to be reduced to such antics in 2022. (There is a related question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/732998/how-can-i-make-my-other-calendars-visible-from-my-outlook-calendar) but Office has changed a lot in the last eight years- surely Microsoft wouldn't have ignored this obvious low-hanging fruit!)

Comment: Looks like there isn't a way to do this built-in- if you run into this problem maybe upvote this feedback item: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/f2b6907a-08c6-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008

Comment: Yes, this is a website dedicated to collecting feedback provided by Microsoft. We can post our suggestions or vote for the expected functions on it.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of research on this, such as changing the permission of other calendar folder, but I haven't found any way to display free and busy information for other calendars. In additon, I also tried to do research and test to check if there're any way can be used to move events of other calendars to "My calendar" folder, but I still got nothing. I'm afraid you need to move them manually.

Comment: The best I could do is overlay them and copy and paste... Of course, if the internet calendar changes, I have to sync it manually... Microsoft and its products are a bad joke at this point, the only reason I use them is because work.